# Instead of Primary Key Send Different Field in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

<kbd>serializers.py</kbd>

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [
            'popularity',
            'director',
            'genre',
            'imdb_score',
            'name',
        ]
```

<kbd>views.py</kbd>

```
class MovieList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        if isinstance(data, list):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I send my data like this and it works correctly.

```
{
   "popularity": 83.0,
   "director": "Victor Fleming",
   "genre": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
   ],
   "imdb_score": 8.3,
   "name": "The Wizard of Oz"
}
```

But I want to send the data somewhat like this:

```
{
   "popularity": 83.0,
   "director": "Victor Fleming",
   "genre": [
      "Adventure",
      "Family",
      "Fantasy",
      "Musical"
   ],
   "imdb_score": 8.3,
   "name": "The Wizard of Oz"
}
```

See the Genre List - Instead of Primary Key I am sending `name`.

These are my Models:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)  # make unique

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    popularity = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    imdb_score = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Even when I am listing data or getting the data it should send genre name instead of id. I tried to use `StringRelatedField`, but it gave me error.

> NotImplementedError at /api/movie/
>   StringRelatedField.to_internal_value() must be implemented.

Comment: Please show your `GenreSerializer`.

Comment: @cezar there is no `GenreSerializer``

Comment: Do you genere `name` is unique ?

Comment: Yes it is unique @Shakil

Comment: Did you use `StringRelatedField` in `MovieSerializer` like this: `name = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)` before the `class Meta`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Override the **`create()`** method of the serializer as below,

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.CharField())

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [
            'popularity',
            'director',
            'genre',
            'imdb_score',
            'name',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        genre = validated_data.pop('genre',[])
        movie = super().create(validated_data)
        genre_qs = Genre.objects.filter(name__in=genre)
        movie.genre.add(*genre_qs)
        return movie
```

Comment: What would I need to change to use this answer for a required field? super().create(validated_data) would fail in that case.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming that you used `StringRelatedField` in your `MovieSerializer` like this:

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [
            'popularity',
            'director',
            'genre',
            'imdb_score',
            'name',
        ]
```

the result would look like this when retrieving a list of movies:

```
[
    {
        "popularity": 83.0,
        "director": "Victor Fleming",
        "genre": [
             "Adventure",
             "Family",
             "Fantasy",
             "Musical"
        ],
        "imdb_score": 8.3,
        "name": "The Wizard of Oz"
    }
]
```

But if you want to create a new movie, then it won't work because `StringRelatedField` is read-only.

You can however create your custom related field.

This is the complete **`serializers.py`**:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Genre, Movie


class GenreRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return Genre.objects.get(name=data)


class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre = GenreRelatedField(
        queryset=Genre.objects.all(),
        many=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = (
            'popularity',  
            'director',     
            'genre',                         
            'imdb_score',
            'name',
        )
```

This is a simple example that can be highly customized in many ways.

The method `display_value` defines how the object Genre is displayed, for example in the form. Here it just returns the object Genre i.e. the output of `__str__`.

The method `to_representation` defines how the object Genre is displayed in the output (JSON or XML). It's very similar to the previous method, but here we explicitly have to convert Genre to string. Certainly you can create a more complex output according to your requirements.

The method `to_internal_value` solves your actual problem by getting an object Genre for the given value. If you have a more complex method `to_representation` here you would need expanded logics to get the appropriate object.

Using this approach you can post a JSON in your desired form, specifying the genre names instead of their ids.

I hope this example helps other people too.

Comment: I like this answer, because it is easy to extend and allows for more complex solution than the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

On solution is to override `genre` field in your serializer, to accept a list of strings like this:

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    genre = serializer.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = [
            'popularity',
            'director',
            'genre',
            'imdb_score',
            'name',
        ]  
    def validate(self, data):
        genre = data.get('genre', [])
        genre_obj_list = [Genre.objects.get(name=name) for name in genre.all()]
        data.update({'genre': genre_obj_list})
        return data
```

And on validate method try to fetch each object by their names and put in a new list and update `data` result with new list of objects. (I know it's not the cleanest solutions, but it works fine)

you could also try to use `MethodSerializer` or define a `GenreSerializer` and fetch objects in that by their names and use that in the parent serializer as an input.

Comment: it is giving error - `TypeError at /api/movie/
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: @HuzaifSayyed try `[Genre.objects.get(name=name) for name in genre.all()]`

Comment: Shouldn't `validate()` call `super()` at some point to validate the other fields?

Comment: Your answer was almost correct. See the accepted answer

Comment: I fixed the problem. problem was `genre.all()` that Now i added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution would be to change the `Genre` model to use `name` as primary key, like so:

```py
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
```

Not that it matters much here, but this will also save a column in the database, since the auto generated `id` column will disappear :)

---

**Update**

After some discussion in the comments to this answer, I find it important to mentions that using ANY type as primary key, you should also avoid changing that field afterwards.

This is because a change to the primary key, also necessitates an update to all the foreign keys pointing to that primary key, and (to put it in terms of this question) even though your table with genres may be relatively small, you may have a significant amount of movies pointing to each genre.

Comment: Yes, this will work, but using strings as primary key is a terribly bad practice.

Comment: Yes i agree @cezar. But i don't want my stucture to be destroy

Comment: @cezar why is it such a "terribly bad practice"?
Sometimes convenience and ease of use just beats everything else. In this case I find it more important to consider this: How many genres do you plan to add? Surely it's not millions, or even many thousands, and you have already limited the field to 30 chars, which is less than the the characters of a UUID, which is sometimes, rightfully, used as primary key.

Comment: In addition to the above, letting `name` be unique already results in two indexes being created (one for the primary key, and one for the unique constraint), so making `name` primary key, increases performance of lookup in this table. The only impact I can think that would argue against this, is that foreign key indices in other tables would be bigger. However, again with UUID in mind, I believe this to be negligible.

Comment: There are plenty of articles in internet explaining why it is a bad practice. As I wrote before, this will work. Here it's not a big deal, but it's still a bad practice and should be avoided. What if you decide to rename a Genre after few hundred movies have been tagged with it? Or merge genres together? Not an unsolvable problem, but why not avoding a bad practice from the beginning.

Comment: @cezar after reading a bit up on it, I realized that every time I make use of a `CharField` as primary key, I follow the rule that you mention, that should be followed for all primary keys: "Avoid modifying primary keys", I usually block modifications by adding `editable=False` to the declaration, unless I need to let the user define it. I will update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

If you always pass name to your serializer, you can add foreign-key field in Model defination. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column) For you case

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    popularity = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, db_column='name')
    imdb_score = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: This is actually a valid answer i guess. relative [read](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) explanation. Its very disappointing that some one trying to put a value, even thats not relevant or not appropriate you think you should always put a comment about that then you can down vote this. Down Voting without commenting is very disappointing.

Comment: I support you @Shakil

Comment: @HuzaifSayyed you should not up vote for this. If you think my answer is value adding then just do that. Thank you for your support.

Comment: i found your answer helpful that's why I have upvoted you. May be not the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SerializerMethodField` then no need to modify your Model.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but the owner of the question got the correct answer and accepted. it will be great if you give answers to the new questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the serializer field method. This will preserve the PK declaration on the model and you can exclude the field of the ForeignKey.

Example:

```py
    class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        """Example Serializer."""

    foreignkey_name: Union[SerializerMethodField, str] = SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_foreignkey_name(instance: Product) -> str:
        """
        Get the foreignkey.name value.

        Parameters
        ----------
        instance: Model

        Returns
        -------
        str
        """
        try:
            return instance.product_type.name
   
        except AttributeError:
            return "Product Type field name has no value"

    class Meta:
        """
        Set the foreignkey model and fields.
        """

        model: Type[ForeignKeyModel] = ForeignKeyModel
        exclude: tuple[str, str] = foreignkey_field # this will exclude the default foreignkey field in the serializer that contains the FK pk.
```