# how to add data to child model along with parent mode?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am working with Django REST framework. I want to add data to child model along with the parent model. Basically creating two records at a time.

**models.py**

```
class Visit(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICE, max_length=1)
   mobile = models.CharField(max_length=18,default="")
   email = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
   address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
   visit_type = models.IntegerField(choices=VISIT_TYPE)
   visit_purpose = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   visitor_photo = models.FileField(upload_to="visitor/",null=True, blank=True)
   id_photo = models.FileField(upload_to="id_card/",null=True, blank=True)
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

class Status(models.Model):
   visit = models.ForeignKey(Visit,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   from_time = models.DateField()
   to_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   aproved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   visit_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   exit_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class StatusSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
         model = Status
         fields = "__all__"
class VisitSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   visit = StatusSerializers(many=True)
   class Meta:
       model = Visit
       fields = "__all__"

   def create(self, validated_data):
      print(validated_data)
      model_b = Visit.objects.create(**validated_data)
      # print(self.context.request.data.get('description'))
      child_model_data = {
         'description': self.context.request.data.get('description'),
      }
      child_model_serializer = StatusSerializers(data=child_model_data)
      child_model_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      child_model_serializer.save(status=model_b)

      return model_b
```

**views.py**

```
  @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
  def create_visitor(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       visitor = Visit.objects.all()
       serializer = VisitSerializers(visitor,context={'request': request},many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
       serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data,context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,
```

status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
In the above code I am able to create child record i.e. Status model record but I don't know how to add other fields to it during its creation.

Comment: Do you want to add record(s) to status model as well as visit model?

Comment: yes,i need to create both recods in one shot.am able to create recod in Status model(ignoreing other fields) but dont know how to add other filds data to Status recod field.

Answer (score 2):

In your `serializer` child model data can be found in `self.context.request.data` and you can simply use child serializer to validate and save in db.

```
class VisitSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Visit
       fields = "__all__"

   def create(self, validated_data):
      print(validated_data)
      model_b = Visit.objects.create(**validated_data)
      child_model_data = {
         'field': self.context['request'].data.get('your_field');
         .....
      }
      child_model_serializer = ChildSerializer(data=child_model_data)
      child_model_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      child_model_serializer.save()

      return model_b
```

#### Update you need to change in multiple places

First in your view, in post method serializer initialization you need to pass context object.

```
  @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
  def create_visitor(request):
     if request.method == 'GET':
        visitor = Visit.objects.all()
        serializer = VisitSerializers(visitor,context={'request': request},many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And then in your VisitSerializer

```
class VisitSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   visit = StatusSerializers(many=True)  # not sure why you did this, this should be removed i guess
   class Meta:
       model = Visit
       fields = "__all__"

   def create(self, validated_data):
      print(validated_data)
      model_b = Visit.objects.create(**validated_data)
      # print(self.context.request.data.get('description'))
      child_model_data = {
         'description': self.context.request.data.get('description'),
          'status': model_b
          # and make sure all other necessary fields.
      }
      child_model_serializer = StatusSerializers(data=child_model_data)
      child_model_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      child_model_serializer.save()

      return model_b
```

Comment: Can you please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55161052/instead-of-primary-key-send-different-field-in-django-rest-framework @shakil

Comment: how to pass data {"parent_fileds":"something"} how to pass for child model. also i dont see parent model is related to child mode via FK

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza you are using `drf-serializer` right ? then in you `request` you can pass relative fields of both of your parent and child model.

Comment: File "/home/netzary/cliftonprojects/mvisiter/api/views.py", line 25, in create_visitor
    serializer.save()
  File "/home/netzary/cliftonprojects/venvs/mvisiter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/netzary/cliftonprojects/mvisiter/api/serializer.py", line 30, in create
    print(self.context.request.data.get('description'))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza please make sure you are passing `context={'request': request}` in your post serializer, just like your get method.

Comment: i havent changed any thing in views.py is same

Comment: In your post method ` serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data)` should change to ` serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data,context={'request': request} )`

Comment: {
    "status": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}    in postman

Comment: what i can see in your post that `status=model_b` so you need to make you , you add that to your child_model_data.

Comment: `'description': self.context.request.data.get('description'),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'request'` now I am getting this.@Shakil

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza can you please update your code for this. It will be helpful to me give you appropriate answer.

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza edited my response. Please feel free to ask if you have any doubt.

Comment: there is nor error as of now.can you tell how to pass fields in Postman or in DRF web interface. when i post i get error like in postman `{
    "visit": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}`

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza why you even added the visit field in your serializer. I just point out a comment that, this seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Shakil if i remove that line got `File "/home/netzary/cliftonprojects/mvisiter/api/views.py", line 60, in create_visitor
    serializer.save()
  File "/home/netzary/cliftonprojects/venvs/mvisiter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/netzary/cliftonprojects/mvisiter/api/serializer.py", line 57, in create
    'description': self.context.request.data.get('description'),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'request'
`

Comment: Clifton please make sure you are passing `serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data, context={'request': request})` this in your post method. If you do his, this error should not come.

Comment: please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285000/1339013) for more details.

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza can you please try with `self.context['request'].data.get('description')` in your serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have extra fields in your serializer along with default fields. For reverse relations, you can add a field like this

```
class VisitSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   status = StatusSerializer(many=True)
   class Meta:
       model = Visit
```

You can pass data to VisitSerializer like this. {, status: [, ]}

Comment: {
"name":"Clifton",
"gender":"M",
"visit_type":1,
"visit_purpose":"xxxxxxx",
status:["description":"xxxxxxx",]
}    got error  as "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 6 column 1 (char 77)"
}

Comment: status should be in quotes. "status"