# How to customize to_internal_value function in a RelatedField class for Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my code I need to make a custom `RelatedField` class for multiple `ModelSerializer` classes. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55164757/5752558), it's working great. But I need to make several `RelatedField` classes for every model I have. Is there any way to only make 1 `RelatedField` class so it can be used for all related fields in my `ModelSerializer`?
Currently I'm doing it like this in `serializers.py`:

```
class ColorRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return ColorParent.objects.get(name=data)


class ProductCollectionRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return ProductCollection.objects.get(name=data)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    collection = ProductCollectionRelatedField(queryset=ProductCollection.objects.all(), many=False)
    color = ColorRelatedField(queryset=ColorParent.objects.all(), many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'product_id', 'collection', 'color', 'video', 'status']
```

How to make `to_internal_value` function returns a dynamic model depending on who calls the method:

```
class CustomRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField, model):
    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return model.objects.get(name=data)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    collection = CustomRelatedField(model=ProductCollection, queryset=ProductCollection.objects.all(), many=False)
    color = CustomRelatedField(model=ColorParent, queryset=ColorParent.objects.all(), many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'product_id', 'collection', 'color', 'video', 'status']
```

When I tried to add `model` parameter in the `CustomRelatedField` class the error message I got was:

> name `model` is not defined.

Comment: What about `model = self.queryset.model`?

Comment: @Charnel When I added `model = self.queryset.model` inside `to_internal_value` function I got a new error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'.

Comment: You don't need to pass `model` as an argument to `CustomRelatedField` because you already passing queryset. Just remove `model` attribute.

Comment: @Charnel thank you so much. It works. I think you would like to post your comment as an answer? So it brings another alternative solution.

Comment: @Nathan Charmel is right! You dont need to pass model at all.

Comment: @Charnel can you post your answer?

Comment: @Nathan glad to help! Posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass `model` as an argument to `CustomRelatedField` because you already passing queryset. Just remove `model` attribute and get the model from queryset like this:

```
 def to_internal_value(self, data):
     model = self.queryset.model
     return model.objects.get(name=data)
```

Comment: @neverwalkaloner & Charnel, I love how contributors in StackOverflow respect each other answers for the greater sake of finding the solution.

Comment: @Nathan that a way of how we can keep helping each other in best way.

Answer (score 2):

Try to override `__init__()` method like this:

```
class CustomRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = kwargs.pop("model")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return self.model.objects.get(name=data)
```

Note `self.model` instead just `model` ins `to_internal_value()`.
Now you can pass model with field's arguments:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    collection = CustomRelatedField(model=ProductCollection, queryset=ProductCollection.objects.all(), many=False)
    color = CustomRelatedField(model=ColorParent, queryset=ColorParent.objects.all(), many=False)
```